# How to mark the text between the parentheses in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Any such function or elisp script? I want the equivalent function as vi" sequence in vim.

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParenthesisMatching

Comment: Here is another version which works better for me: [http://xahlee.org/emacs/syntax_tree_walk.html](http://xahlee.org/emacs/syntax_tree_walk.html)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try the key sequence <kbd>C-M-u C-M-SPC</kbd> (i.e., while holding the <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd> keys, press <kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> in sequence), which executes the commands `backward-up-sexp` and `mark-sexp`.

#### Edit:

I made a mistake: `backward-up-sexp` doesn't exist in standard Emacs.  I wrote it exactly because of the problem mentioned in lkahtz's comment, that the existing function `backward-up-list` won't work when point is between double quotes.

```
(defun backward-up-sexp (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((ppss (syntax-ppss)))
    (cond ((elt ppss 3)
           (goto-char (elt ppss 8))
           (backward-up-sexp (1- arg)))
          ((backward-up-list arg)))))

(global-set-key [remap backward-up-list] 'backward-up-sexp)
```

Comment: One thing.. This seems only works for brackets. As for double quotes, it will mark the point to the next double quote. I have to key in C-M-b to complete the marking.. Any way to conquer this? ( I really look forward to a script and if no one gives better idea, I will write one myself later)...

Answer (score 10):

[expand-region](https://github.com/emacsmirror/expand-region) (which is bound to C-=) works great.

Answer (score 1):

Xah Lee has an emacs-lisp function which achieves this called `xah-select-text-in-quote`. [It is available from his website](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/modernization_mark-word.html):

> Select text between the nearest left and right delimiters.
>   Delimiters here includes the following chars: \"<>(){}[]“”‘’‹›«»「」『』【】〖〗《》〈〉〔〕（）.
>   This command does not properly deal with nested brackets.