# How to select text between quotes, brackets... in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, text-editor

In vim, you can do this by vi", vi[, vi( ...

For example, if you have a line like this:

```
x = "difference between vim and emacs"
```

and the cursor is anywhere between those quotes and you hit vi", then the string will be visually
selected.

Comment: Closely related: [How to mark the text between the parentheses in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5194417/1199226)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Late to the party, but you can also use [Evil mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil), which does a bang-up job of Vim emulation, including the motion commands you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up using! :)

Answer (score 17):

The package [expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) is convenient for this. Calling `er/expand-region` with the point inside the quotes will mark the nearest word, and then calling it again will mark all the words inside the quotes. (Calling it a third time will expand the region to include the quotes.)

I have it bound to `C-;`.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'er/expand-region)
```

With this binding, pressng `C-; C-;` will highlight the text between the quotes.

Comment: @qed If you are selecting the text because you want to operate on it (copy it, kill it, etc.) there's also [change-inner.el](https://github.com/magnars/change-inner.el) which is built on top of `expand-region.el` and "gives you vim's `ci` command".

Answer (score 8):

From [Emacs Documentation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParenthesisMatching)

> Nearly all modes support “(,)” as parentheses, and most also support
>   square brackets “[,]” and curly brackets “{,}”. However, you can make
>   any pair of characters a parenthesis-pair, by using the following
>   command:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?^ "($")
(modify-syntax-entry ?$ ")^")
```

Also, take a look at this post [How to mark the text between the parentheses in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194417/how-to-mark-the-text-between-the-parentheses-in-emacs). key combination given per this post

Try the key sequence `C-M-u C-M-SPC` (i.e., while holding the `Control` and `Meta` keys, press `u` and `Space` in sequence), which executes the commands `backward-up-sexp` and `mark-sexp`

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun select-text-in-delimiters ()
  "Select text between the nearest left and right delimiters."
  (interactive)
  (let (start end)
    (skip-chars-backward "^<>([{\"'")
    (setq start (point))
    (skip-chars-forward "^<>)]}\"'")
    (setq end (point))
    (set-mark start)))
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of the toolkit

https://launchpad.net/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/+download

the following keys/commands are delivered:

```
(global-set-key [(super \))] 'ar-parentized-atpt)
(global-set-key [(super \])] 'ar-bracketed-atpt)
(global-set-key [(super \})] 'ar-braced-atpt)
(global-set-key [(super \")] 'ar-doublequoted-atpt)
(global-set-key [(super \')] 'ar-singlequoted-atpt)
```

That way with a couple of more chars known as delimiters will constitute commands.

`ar-delimited-atpt` will return the string around point found by nearest delimiter.

A group of more powerful commands allows re-using keys like that

```
(global-set-key [(control c)(\")] 'ar-doublequote-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(\')] 'ar-singlequote-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(<)] 'ar-lesser-angle-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(>)] 'ar-greater-angle-or-copy-atpt)
```

Here a doctring given as example:

```
ar-doublequote-or-copy-atpt is an interactive Lisp function in
`thing-at-point-utils.el'.

It is bound to C-c ".

(ar-doublequote-or-copy-atpt &optional NO-DELIMITERS)

If region is highlighted, provide THING at point with doublequote(s),
  otherwise copy doublequote(ed) at point.
  With C-u, copy doublequote(ed) without delimiters. 
  With negative argument kill doublequote(ed) at point.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use libraries [thingatpt+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/emacs-en/thingatpt%2b.el) and [thing-cmds.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/thing-cmds.el).

You will find there commands such as `thing-region`, which selects a thing at point as the region.  Since `string-contents` and `list-contents` are defined as things (in `thingatpt+.el`), these select the string/list contents as the region:

```
(thing-region "string-contents") ; Select the contents of the string at point.
(thing-region "list-contents")   ; Select the contents of the list at point.
```

Or interactively:

```
M-x thing-region RET string-contents RET
```

Other, related commands include:

- `C-M-U` (aka `C-M-S-u`) -- `mark-enclosing-list`: Select enclosing list.  Repeat to expand list levels.  Works with any balanced-parenthesis expressions (e.g., vectors): whatever the current syntax table defines as having balanced-delimiter syntax.
- `mark-thing` -- Select successive things of a given kind (repeating).
- `next-visible-thing` -- Move to the next visible thing of a given kind (repeating).